# JavaScript function that takes a random argument each time

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas, javascript-objects

I'm working on a Canvas API game and I want to create some enemies, each time I create a new instance of the enemy I want it to be create in a new position (not randomly, but rather 3 specific positions.

So let's say I have this function:

```
var enemy = new Enemy(0, Math.random() * 184 + 50, Math.random() * 256);
```

This creates a new enemy with an Y position of 0, an X position which is random and a Speed argument that's also random.

This works fine but I want the enemies to be be created in only 3 specific positons and the speed to only increase by 10 each time new enemy instance is being created.

More info: new enemies are being called once the player get's to the final position of winning, like so:

```
var increaseDifficulty = function(numEnemies) {
    // remove all previous enemies on canvas
    allEnemies.length = 0;

    // load new set of enemies
    for (var i = 0; i <= numEnemies; i++) {
        var enemy = new Enemy(0, Math.random() * 184 + 50, Math.random() * 256);

        allEnemies.push(enemy);
    }
};
```

What I want is a way to create a new enemy with a different argument each time. Only for the position and speed.

Something like:

```
var enemy = new Enemy(0, 1, 1);
```

The second time it is being called it'll be different so:

```
var enemy = new Enemy(0, 3, 2);
```

Of course the values won't be 1, 2 and 3 but you get the idea.

**UPDATE:** 
The new enemy calls upon this:

```
var Enemy = function(x, y, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
};

Enemy.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    this.x += this.speed * dt;
    if (this.x >= 505) {
        this.x = 0;
    }

    checkCollision(this);
};
Enemy.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `different expression`?

Comment: I meant to say "argument". Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. How many enemies are you creating when you increase difficulty? More specifically, how many times does the `for` loop iterate? How many do you actually want to create? 3? Or 1, but to choose randomly from 3 positions you randomly generate somewhere at the beginning (when you initialize everything)? How do you create the first enemy?

Comment: Please, edit your question to add more info. Don't add info as an answer.

Comment: Ok, done, do you guys still don't understand the question?

Comment: How would knowing how many enemy instances are created matter in any way?

Comment: You wrote that `Y` is always 0 but in your examples you pass 0 to `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` is always 0 so there is no point passing it to the constructor, `speed` has some starting value and then is always increased by 10 so there is no point passing it too. `X` is the only thing that is random, and there is some point to pass it to the constructor, but I would not do that too. I would create an array of possible values of `X` and choose one of them randomly inside the constructor.

```js
const xValues = [20, 60, 100];

//The Enemy "class":
function Enemy() {
    this.y = 0;
    this.x = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * xValues.length)];
    Enemy.speed = (Enemy.speed += 10) || 10;
    this.speed = Enemy.speed;
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
}

let e1 = new Enemy;
console.log(e1);
let e2 = new Enemy;
console.log(e2);
let e3 = new Enemy;
console.log(e3);
```

*Note 1:* `Math.floor(Math.random() * xValues.length)` creates a random *integer* (thanks to the `Math.floor`) number between 0 and the length on my `xValues` array. This number is used to choose a random value from the `xValues` array.

*Note 2:* on this line I create something like a class variable `Enemy.speed` with the starting value of 10.  At first `Enemy.speed` does not exist so `Enemy.speed += 10` evaluates to `NaN`, since `NaN` is falsy the evaluating continues to `10`;

```
Enemy.speed = (Enemy.speed += 10) || 10;
```

Then I copy the value to the instance.

```
this.speed = Enemy.speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know entire project, so this is only example/draft:

```
const createEnemiesFactory = pos => {
    let lastPos = -1;
    let lastSpeed = 0;
    return () => {
        lastPos = (lastPos + 1) % pos.length;
        lastSpeed += 10;
        return new Enemy(pos[lastPos].x, pos[lastPos].y, lastSpeed);
    };
};

let enemiesFactory = createEnemiesFactory([
    {x: 0, y: 0},
    {x: 10, y: 10},
    {x: 20, y: 20}
]);

var increaseDifficulty = function(numEnemies) {
    // remove all previous enemies on canvas
    allEnemies.length = 0;

    // load new set of enemies
    for (var i = 0; i <= numEnemies; i++) {
        allEnemies.push( enemiesFactory() );
    }
};
```

Small notice: if you need to reset difficulty (i.e. on restart), than, obviously, recreate enemies factory, because there is no another way to reset `lastSpeed`.